# show that $ \int^\infty_1 \frac{(-1)^{[x]}}{x}dx $ converges

Tags: analysis, integers

I have this exercise, where I have to check whether or not this converges:

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor of $x$.

I would like to use the Dirichlet criterion, but I don't know how to show whether or not this is bounded: $F(x):=\int_1^x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $F$ is bounded in $x>1$, so the Dirichlet criterion does apply.

Hint: you can bound by $1$!

Second hint: split the interval $[1,x]$ into segments where $(-1)^{[t]}$ is positive and negative respectively. What do you notice about the size of these segments? What happens when you write $F$ as a sum of integrals over each segment?

Answer (score 1):

First of all by Dirichlet test, the integral converges.

Now break the integral into each interval $[n,n+1]$ for $n\in\Bbb{N}$ and see that you get $\int_{1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}{x}\,dx=\ln\left(\left(\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^{2}\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)$ where $n!!$ denotes the double factorial.

You can simplify it further to $\ln\left(\frac{(2n+1)^{2}}{(2n+2)}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^{2}}{4^{n}}\right)$ . Now if you properly apply Stirling's approximation , you'll find that in the limit it tends to $\displaystyle\ln(\frac{2}{\pi})$ which will be the value of the integral.